# Mapping sessions to users

Tags: php, apache-flex

When I login a new session is generated. How can I later know for which login the session was generated?

I am getting the session value, but how do I know which user the session is for and redirect him to that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to create a (new) session when the user is logging in. You create/resume the session on every page.

Here some example broken down to the essentials.

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST['user'] == 'john' && $_POST['pwd'] == 'password') {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn']  = true;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = 'John';
}
?>
```

**admin.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || !$_SESSION['loggedIn']) {
    header('location: login.php');
    exit();
}

echo 'Hello ' . $_SESSION['firstname'] . '!';
?>
```

- A user visits admin.php
- `session_start()` creates a new session. All data ($_SESSION) is stored on the server. A new cookie with the session's id is stored client-side.
- The user is redirected to login.php in order there is no `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` key set to `true`
- `session_start()` revives the session by the cookie sent by the browser
- The user submits a form and authenticates. Inside the `$_SESSION` array we note this.
- User goes back to admin.php and can now access the page.